# Is it possible to schedule an automated report from a shared document in Google Doc's or Dropbox?

Tags: google-drive-api, report, scheduled-tasks, dropbox

Everyone on my team at work updates a shared document at the end of each business day with the amount of commissions they paid that day. I am wondering, is it possible to have an automated job that sends out the report at say 6pm each day via an email?

All the best! and excuse my noobness.

Comment: this isn't a great SO question. You might want to look at IFTTT

Comment: Ok cool, whats IFTTT?

Comment: You can definitely do this. If you're having trouble, please share some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write automated cron job that can fetch all Drive Docs and check for each file for modified date if date is current date then take all shared users for that file and send mail to each shared user.

Refere **https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list**